# can't take NSDate from dateString

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I've string `@"Sun, 15 Jan 2012 17:09:48 +0000"` I want date from it..
What can I do
I tried

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"DDD, DD MMM YYYY HH:MM:SS +HHMM"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:stringDate];
but date was nslogged with null
```

Comment: Can you give us the string that the date tried to parse?  That might help determine why it's returning null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format is incorrect and [here is why](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

```
Sun, 15 Jan 2012 17:09:48 +0000
DDD, DD MMM YYYY HH:MM:SS +HHMM
^^^  ^^     ^^^^    ^^ ^^ ^^^^^ < Treating the last 2 digits of the timezone as months
^^^  ^^     ^^^^    ^^ ^^ ^^^ < Treating the first 2 digits of the timezone as hours
^^^  ^^     ^^^^    ^^ ^^ ^ < Hardcoding the + (timezone can handle that)
^^^  ^^     ^^^^    ^^ ^^ < Using fractional seconds (not a big deal)
^^^  ^^     ^^^^    ^^ < Using months instead of minutes
^^^  ^^     ^^^^ < Using weak year instead of calendar year
^^^  ^^ < Using day of year instead of day of the month
^^^ < Using day of year instead of day of the week
```

Here is the correct format `"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"`

Answer (score 1):

incorrect `dateFormat:`, use this:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
```

[image: timezone unicode example]

more on : http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Time_Zone_Fallback

Answer (score 0):

Your date format is probably wrong. Check the documentation here:

http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Try that: `E, d MMM y HH:mm:ss Z`

Answer (score 0):

Well, there a couple things I see wrong.  I think you need to review the date formatter guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1.

First off, the format is case sensitive.  Soo... capital 'M' is month, lowercase 'm' is minute.  Day is lowercase 'd'. Year is lowercase 'y'.  There's probably other mistakes you've made but this should get you started in the right direction.